# partitionBy assigns partitions, but WHERE in each partition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

With hash function:

```
balanceLoad = lambda x: bisect.bisect_left(boundary_array, -keyfunc(x))
```

Where boundary_array is [-64, -10, 35]

The folowing tells me which partition to assign each element to

```
rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions, balanceLoad)
```

However, is there a way to determine /control WHERE in each partition they are assigned / placed? {1,2,3} vs {3,2,1}.

For example when I do this:

```
rdd = CleanRDD(sc.parallelize(range(100), 4).map(lambda x: (x *((-1) ** x) , x)))

sortByKey(rdd, keyfunc=lambda key: key, ascending=False).collect()
```

Elements in each partition are in reverse order:

[(64, 64),
 (66, 66),
 (68, 68),
 (70, 70),
 (72, 72),
 (74, 74),
 (76, 76),
 (78, 78),
 (80, 80),
 (82, 82),
 (84, 84),
 (86, 86),
 (88, 88),
 (90, 90),
 (92, 92),
 (94, 94),
 (96, 96),
 (98, 98),
 (10, 10),
 (12, 12),
 (14, 14),
 (16, 16),
 (18, 18),
 (20, 20),
 (22, 22),
 (24, 24),
 (26, 26),
 (28, 28),
 (30, 30),
 (32, 32),
 (34, 34),
 (36, 36),
 (38, 38),
 (40, 40),
 (42, 42),
 (44, 44),
 (46, 46),
 (48, 48),
 (50, 50),
 (52, 52),
 (54, 54),
 (56, 56),
 (58, 58),
 (60, 60),
 (62, 62),
 (-35, 35),
 (-33, 33),
 (-31, 31),
 (-29, 29),
 (-27, 27),
 (-25, 25),
 (-23, 23),
 (-21, 21),
 (-19, 19),
 (-17, 17),
 (-15, 15),
 (-13, 13),
 (-11, 11),
 (-9, 9),
 (-7, 7),
 (-5, 5),
 (-3, 3),
 (-1, 1),
 (0, 0),
 (2, 2),
 (4, 4),
 (6, 6),
 (8, 8),
 (-99, 99),
 (-97, 97),
 (-95, 95),
 (-93, 93),
 (-91, 91),
 (-89, 89),
 (-87, 87),
 (-85, 85),
 (-83, 83),
 (-81, 81),
 (-79, 79),
 (-77, 77),
 (-75, 75),
 (-73, 73),
 (-71, 71),
 (-69, 69),
 (-67, 67),
 (-65, 65),
 (-63, 63),
 (-61, 61),
 (-59, 59),
 (-57, 57),
 (-55, 55),
 (-53, 53),
 (-51, 51),
 (-49, 49),
 (-47, 47),
 (-45, 45),
 (-43, 43),
 (-41, 41),
 (-39, 39),
 (-37, 37)]

Notice that elements in each of the three groups are in reverse order.
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Determine no, because an order of the shuffle is nondeterministic.

You can control the order but not as a part of the partitioning process or at least not in PySpark. Instead you can take a similar approach like `sortByKey` and enforce the order per partition afterwards:

```
def applyOrdering(iter):
    """Takes an itertools.chain object
    and returns iterable with specific ordering"""
    ... 

rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions, balanceLoad).mapPartitions(applyOrdering)
```

Note that `iter` may be to large fit into memory so you should either increase granularity or use sorting mechanism which doesn't require reading all data at once.